# Can't get CSS formatting and script to work together in HTA

Tags: css, vbscript, hta

I have a problem with running any script from HTA file because of meta tag.

If I run application without meta tag, then CSS does not work correctly but I can run a script. When I include meta tag, I cannot run any script (undefined), but CSS is fine then

I have already tried with different meta tags.
When I remove `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">`, then CSS does not work, but closing script does. When I add this piece of code, then it shows error: "`'ExitForm' is undefined`"

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Checklist</title>

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="objHTAHelpomatic" APPLICATIONNAME="Checklist" SCROLL="no" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" WINDOWSTATE="maximize" />

<style type="text/css">
.inputGroup {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.inputGroup label {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3c454c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inputGroup label:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  background-color: #5562eb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.inputGroup label:after {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #d1d7dc;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='32' height='32' viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.414 11L4 12.414l5.414 5.414L20.828 6.414 19.414 5l-10 10z' fill='%23fff' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.inputGroup input:checked ~ label {
  color: #fff;
}
.inputGroup input:checked ~ label:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.inputGroup input:checked ~ label:after {
  background-color: #54e0c7;
  border-color: #54e0c7;
}
.inputGroup input {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.form {
  padding: 0 16px;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 36px;
}
body {
  background-color: #d1d7dc;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
code {
  background-color: #9aa3ac;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
</style>
</head>

<script Language="VBScript">
Sub ExitForm()
    Close
End Sub
</script>
<body>
<form class="form">
    <div class="inputGroup">
        <input id="option1" name="option1" type="checkbox" checked />
        <label for="option1">dupa</label>
    </div>
</form>
<input class="button" type="button" value="CLOSE" name="close"  onClick="ExitForm"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<meta ... content="IE=edge">` -> `<meta ... content="IE=8">`.

Comment: There is the same situation - with such content CSS does not work.

Comment: If you want to use `IE=edge` (or `IE=10`) you MUST implement the code in JavaScript. VBScript will not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right - this is what I did, but now I have another problem.

Comment: In my HTA application I have a form with checkboxes. 
I need to send  values of those checkboxes (True or False) to Excel Macro. 
I was thinking about creating text file with those values, but it is not very easy in JavaScript. 
Is there any way to send such values to Excel Macro or to VBScript?